# Using vlookup with repeated interval + split

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a list with purchase codes and product serial number and would like to know the purchase price of each product.
In a second list, I have a column with the purchase code, the serial number of a comma-separated product group in another column, and, in the third column, the price of each product group.

I am using the formula below, but when the codes in column "E" are repeated, the formula does not work:

```
=IF(HLOOKUP(B2;SPLIT(VLOOKUP(A2;$E$1:$F$1000;2;FALSE);", ";TRUE);1;FALSE)<>"#N/A";VLOOKUP(A2;$E$1:$G$5;3;FALSE);"")
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhIJF.png)

[Test Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HX2eko7v15mDja6_KlajmUaHkY4SCmKfELvPxqgnDUA/edit#gid=0)

Comment: I would suggest using Apps Script, since it would make working with this more comfortable, if this is acceptable I can give you a hand with the script itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a query

```
=query(E:G,"select G where E='"&A2&"' and F contains '"&B2&"' limit 1 label G ''")
```

provided none of the IDs in column B can be a substring of another ID.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of writing the Apps Script code for what you need, this is it:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getRange("B2:B" + ss.getLastRow()).getValues(); // IDs
  var list = ss.getRange("F2:G" + ss.getLastRow()).getValues(); // ID List
  var prices = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++){     
      if (list[j][0].indexOf(data[i][0]) >- 1){
        prices.push([list[j][1]]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  ss.getRange("C2:C" + ss.getLastRow()).setValues(prices);
}
```

it does the check based on the ID List values and the ID itself, it's not doing anything with the `cod` value.

Comment: Thanks! Very cool, AMolina.
Could you tell me which trigger is best for me to call this function? (It's a spreadsheet that multiple users work on)

Comment: You could use an `onEdit()` trigger, it would run the script whenever a change is made to is, so it keeps it updated with the latest data. [This documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) explains more on triggers and how to set them up.